# The android java class cannot recognize the R file

Tags: java, android

I had two layout files on R.java and I checked it was there on R.java(written on it). But strangely the java class cannot recognize the layout and keep saying that the layout cannot be resolved.  I Have Run the project but it keep saying that my project contains error. Is this some kind of bugs?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If yes then clean the project from project -> clean.. If issue is going on, make sure you are not importing android.R class in your Activity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the import section of your java class. Sometimes Eclipse incorrectly imports `android.R` class instead of one generated in your project.

Comment: Done. Just as you said the culprit was the android.R file. thanks

Comment: @Karate_Dog how did you do that.. I mean I dont know how to... I just don't know how to check or where to check imports stated on the answer.

Comment: @Raf It's the import section at the beginning of the .java file that have compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

check if you have R imported (it shouldn't)
delete R (it should generate itself)
clean project
run

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your XML files have no errors before using anything referenced in the R.java file.
R.java isn't built if there are errors in your XML files.

Answer (score 1):

This must be for 2 reason normaly.

You have a error in some xml of your project

You must to clean the proyect (project  -  clean - clean project)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Console. It should contain some error messages which prevent the R file from being generated.

Comment: This question had been resolved 3 years ago dude. But here's an upvote

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in Android Studio. A gradle build fixed the issue. Hope a ant/gradle rebuild of the project will fix the broken dependency.