# Android & Java: what is the odd object called `R`?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to understand Android TCP client and Server communication, illustrated [here](http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/comment-page-2/#comment-1822) and errs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z828L.png). I get all the time `"R cannot be resolved to a variable"` and it is used like the below. What is this R -object that has methods such as `layout` and `id`?

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
textDisplay = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

*P.s. You can find the codes in GitHub `tcpcommclient` and `tcpcommserver` [here](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial).*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understand the R class in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

R is a static class that lists all your resources (usually defined in XML, but all available in your res folder).

For more info: [Understand the R class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android)

edit: According to here: [The android java class cannot recognize the R file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144475/the-android-java-class-cannot-recognize-the-r-file)
one of your classes might actually be importing the R.java class. Never do that. If there are imports of that class, remove them.

Also, You might to clean the project (project - clean - clean project)

Comment: ...can you say how to solve this undefined problem? It is automatically-generated so how can I initialize it in eclipse?

Comment: Try to clean your project and build again.

Comment: I don't know yet what I should do in Eclipse -- anyway trying and copying them again to new projcet -- I downloaded the codes [here](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~he/multicastMe.tgz).

Comment: Updated with 2 suggestions including link to similar question.

Comment: I removed the generated R -thing in trying to clean things, now I am not sure how I can get it back. Ideas? Sorry I am a bit jammed.

Comment: Clean your project, it should be generated then: Procject menu -> clean -> clean project.

Comment: If it is not generated, you might have an error in one of your resource files. Fix that and R.java should be generated.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the problem by using default import -features. In copy-pasting, it is easy to mess up things.